# Get UITextField default layer iOS 7

Tags: ios, properties, uitextfield, layer, cornerradius

How can I get the values of the properties `layer.borderWidth`, `layer.borderColor` and `layer.cornerRadius` of a default `UITextField`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can access directly to textfield layer, after imported `QuartzCore` framework:

```
  UITextField *txt = //init here;

  NSLog(@"%f", txt.layer.borderWidth);
  NSLog(@"%@", txt.layer.borderColor);
  NSLog(@"%f", txt.layer.cornerRadius);
```

hope this help.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't use a UITextField in my project, I just want the exact values in order to make my UITextView border looks exactly like a UITextField.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I need the very same answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer for the question (**how can I...?**).